# "App is not review app" when tried deleting Heroku Review App

Tags: heroku, review

Heroku provides a feature for creating review apps for your git Pull Requests and shared with others for any feedback. I have created and deleted many review apps in the past. But suddenly, I started getting this error "App is not review app" when I tried deleting my recent review app. Please help!

Comment: Please elaborate your question, give specific details of what triggered this error (what did you do before it was raised)

Comment: Like earlier, I had created a review app. Since, I no longer needed it...I tried deleting it. But I started getting this error "Item could not be removed -> App is not review app".

Comment: Was able to delete from view initial app setup -> settings -> delete app. Thank you.